# No block device created on connected USB drive after updates

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

for months now I've been doing physical backup from an Ubuntu Server 20.04 to USB drives I swap out and take off site.  No rocket science, I plug in the drive, mount the block device, typically /dev/sdb1 and I'm off.

The drives have NTFS partitions, and are 4GB in size.  Now since yesterday and some routine updates neither of my two identical USB drives will get a block device created on plugging it in to the Linux host.  Both show up fine in Windoze.  I went so far as to reformat one, both gain as NTFS and once as xfat.  Neither action resulted in any changed behaviour when plugging it into the  Ubuntu host.

The block device /dev/sdb eventually show up after plugging it in - but only after a very long time.

```
# file /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: block special (8/16)
```

but I fdisk can't "see" it:

```
# fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No such file or directory
```

Nothing shows with lsblk or blkid I guess since the block device is never created.

Any suggestions what to try to get this working again?

Comment: Does the Windows system you're plugging the drives into (why else use NTFS?) have Windows' "Fast Boot" enabled? Windows' "Fast Boot" leaves the disks in an unreadable condition.

Comment: I don't care what filesystem is used, as long as it can accept large files, these are VM snapshot files.  I simply used NTFS as it was already on the drives when I bought them.  The Windows PC does have fast boot enabled, but has had so for years and the issue only started this week and specifically after doing an update on the host.  It's a concern because fdisk can't format it as a Linux partition because it's not able to access it.

Comment: Has anyone else seen anything like this?  I have 2 servers now that I cannot use to access this USB drive.  The USB tools "see" the device, but with no block devioce to associate with it I cannot access it.

I am stumped as to how to force the block device to be crreated.